# Detect if a key should be treated as a style or attribute

Tags: javascript, css, dom, styling

I have the following function :

```
var applyStyling = function (element, object) {
    return _.each(object, function (value, key) {
       // determine whether the key should be treated as an attribute or style 
         if(style)
            element.style.key = value
         element.setAttribute(key, value)
    })
}
```

An example use would be something like

```
applyStyling('some dom element', {'id' : 'someID', 'zIndex' : 10})
```

How can I detect if the key should be treated as a style or attribute? I could only find how to check if attribute/style has been set on an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var applyStyling = function (element, object) {
    return _.each(object, function (value, key) {
       // determine whether the key should be treated as an attribute or style 
         if(element.hasAttribute(key))
             element.setAttribute(key, value)
         else if (element.style.hasOwnProperty(key))
             element.style[key] = value
    })
}
```

Edit: modified answer based on OP comment

```
var applyStyling = function (element, object) {
    return _.each(object, function (value, key) {
       // determine whether the key should be treated as an attribute or style 
         if (element.style.hasOwnProperty(key))
             element.style[key] = value
         else
             element.setAttribute(key, value)
    })
}
```

Comment: My specific use case is for SVG elements. Keys that should definitely be attributes do not respond like attributes. For example, 'x1', 'y1', etc for SVG lines respond like they are styles.

Comment: @user3619165 then check first if it's a style and if not then assume it's attribute

Answer (score 0):

I´m afraid there is no quick answer. You can list/check already defined properties. But how could you **pre-list** user-defined properties on DOM elements or browser-defined properties like style ones.

You can even use the same name for both ( with reserve ), setting element.zIndex and element.style.id would do no wrong.

Nice Hack. **pre-list** for your use and abuse.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var applyStyling = function (element, object) {
  for(var key in object) if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    if(element.style[key] !== void 0)
      element.style[key] = object[key];
    else
      element.setAttribute(key, object[key]);
  }
}
```

```js
var applyStyling = function (element, object) {
  for(var key in object) if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    if(element.style[key] !== void 0)
      element.style[key] = object[key];
    else
      element.setAttribute(key, object[key]);
  }
}
applyStyling(document.documentElement, {
  color: 'red',
  title: 'tooltip'
});
```

```html
Some text
```